# How can I change my IMDb account settings to use openID for login

Tags: security, login, openid, imdb

I have an imbd.com account that I login to using an **id** and a **password**, I noticed recently that they support logging in using Facebook, Amazon and Google.

I very much prefer using my Google account to login to other sites, is it possible to change the way I login to my IMDb account without having to create a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a way, but being a new feature it isn't documented. Judging from their similar FAQ topic on how to [merge with a Facebook](http://www.imdb.com/help/search?domain=helpdesk_faq&index=1&file=facebookaccount) account, it wouldn't be pretty (or ideal - comments, message board posts and a bunch of other stuff are lost).

Your best bet will be to ask at the [IMDB Help Desk](http://www.imdb.com/contact) unless a new FAQ gets posted soon.

Comment: thanks incarnate, I [posted](http://www.imdb.com/board/bd0000041/thread/200392859) on IMDb forum and got a reply that solved my issue.

all I needed to do, is to choose to log in using Google, IMDb checks if they have an account associated with the email address, I was prompted if I wish to start logging in to that account using Google instead of IMDb username/password.
worked like a charm :)

Comment: nice one - sounds much better than what I found!

Comment: Yep, you have to email-juggle but it works; I succesfully changed the email of my account three times to link it with Amazon and Google (changing to the addresses I used on those services) and then get back on my original email and now all the logins bring to the same account. :)